# how to handle encoded cyrillic data in json using Qt?

Tags: c++, json, qt, encoding, decode

I have a JSON but all cyrillic characters are encoded like this: `\u0418\u0437\u0431\u0435`.
How can I read this into QString?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's JSON's Unicode escape sequence. You should use a JSON parser for this. There are some other gotchas in JSON parsing.

If you are using Qt 5, it comes with one: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qjsondocument.html

If you are not, then get a 3rd party one like [jsoncpp](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/). It's rather lightweight and not to difficult to convert between its data and Qt's.

Answer (score 1):

That's should be an UTF8 or UTF16 encoding. Use this:

```
result = QString::fromUtf8(yourString.c_str(), yourString.size());
```

or

```
result = QString::fromUtf16(yourString.c_str(), yourString.size());
```

where yourString is std::string type

Comment: it doesn't works. Actually I'm receiving the data in QByteArray. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: define your "doesn't work". Does it compile? Run time error? Make an example of what string you give and what string you get (explain if you can't print non-ASCII character in stackoverflow.com)

Comment: it doesn't convert it - it returns the same sequence. I have Json containing escaped Cyrillic characters `\u0418\u0437\u0431\u0435`. When I use `result = QString::fromUtf8(yourString.c_str(), yourString.size());` in result I get the same sequence, not the Cyrillic characters. What to do?